# Using cell values as a date range autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to adjust my date autofilter with a range extracted from 2 cells.

After some failed tries, I decided to do the macro with the macro builder so I could tweak it to adust to my code, and I ended up with:

```
Dim fI As Range
Dim fF As Range

Set fI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B26")

Set fF = Worksheets("Control").Range("B27")


    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TABLE_REPORTS_GENERAL_INFO").Range _
        .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=fI.Value, Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:=fF.Value
```

The dates are in the correct format, but it will just let the filter clean. Hardcoding the dates is working, what am I doing wrong?

My dates structure:

```
Starting Date   01/08/2015
Last Date   31/07/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that you are in a DMY date format. I will try to keep to that regional standard.

Use an array with data types as Criteria2.

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .ListObjects("TABLE_REPORTS_GENERAL_INFO")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
            Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(fi.Value, "d/m/yyyy"), 2, Format(ff.Value, "d/m/yyyy"))
    End With
End With
```

That should filter for the two dates. However, if you want all the dates between a start date and an end date then you need to introduce operators.

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .ListObjects("TABLE_REPORTS_GENERAL_INFO")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
            Criteria1:=Format(fi.Value, "\>\=d/m/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:=Format(ff.Value, "\<\=d/m/yyyy")
    End With
End With
```

Comment: You're right about using between dates, however, I think that you need to escape the `<` (e.g. `format(Now, "\<=d/m/yyyy")`) .   When I tested `format(Now, "<=d/m/yyyy")` in the immediate window it returned `=d/m/yyyy8/31/2016 1:48:12 am`

Comment: This throws an error, method autofilter off class Range.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - Thanks for catching that; I ended up escaping tboth teh operator and the equals.

Comment: The equals tested okay but it doesn't hurt to escape it.  Just returning the favor.

Comment: @Jeeped the second solution is doing the same my code was doing before, leave the filter clear/empty.

Comment: I've performed full testing and made two minor adjustments. It works on my system no matter whether I am set to DMY or MDY.

Comment: I've checked the dates and they are not the problem, I have no idea what is failing...

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your second range to `fechaFin`, but later you only use `fF`, so try assigning your range like this: `Set fF = Worksheets("Control").Range("B27")`

Because right now `fF.Value` is an empty string, which will probably reset the filter