# Copy each value in a row to another workbook where a value matches?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks.

Workbook A

```
Supplier Name        Date

Supplier A         Jun-17
Supplier B         Jun-17
Supplier C         May-17
```

Workbook B

```
Supplier Name
Supplier A
Supplier B
```

I am trying to copy all supplier names where they match the date Jun-17.
Jun-17 is written on a sheet called (assets) in cell B1.

I am getting an error

```
Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

On this line:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Format(Range("O" & j).Value, "mmm") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assets").Range("b1").Value Then
```

My code:

```
Sub Monthly()


On Error Resume Next

UserForm1.Show
If Format(Range("O211").Value, "mmm") = Worksheets("assets").Range("b1").Value Then
MsgBox "Yes"
End If

Dim WB As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks("PAI Monthly Audits.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\QUALITY ASSURANCE\03_AUDITS\PAI\templates\PAI Monthly Audits.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False)
End If



With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 6

    For i = 2 To LastRow


        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Format(Range("O" & j).Value, "mmm") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assets").Range("b1").Value Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & j).Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
    Next i
End With



End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Off-topic tip:  `On Error Resume Next` can make debugging an incredibly difficult challenge.  This happens because it hides errors from you.  Consider commenting this out during testing, and if possible, refactoring your code to catch, not suppress, errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
If Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("O" & j).Value, "mmm") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assets").Range("b1").Value Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime error can be corrected with the suggestions already made (the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` should used to identify the parent of `Range("O" & j)`, not of `Format`) but that doesn't mean your code will work. As a true date, `17-Jun-2017` has a raw value of 42,903. `Format(42903, "mmm")` returns `"Jun"` as a text string. The text *Jun* **does not** equal 42903.

If both Assets!B1 and the dates in 'Workbook A' column O are true dates then you only have to compare their raw values '*to copy all supplier names where they match the date Jun-17*'.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("O" & j).Value2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assets").Range("b1").Value2 Then
```

Beyond that, using AutoFilter to select all of the rows with 17-Jun-2017 dates would be more efficient. See [Using cell values as a date range autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242190/using-cell-values-as-a-date-range-autofilter/39242452?s=1|2.9498#39242452). Even using an INDEX/MATCH function pair to the closed workbook might be preferable.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assets")` ? Don't you open a workbook called PAI Monthly Audits.xlsx?